# Bootstrap Margin Top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi first sorry my english. I will try to tell the with image.

I have 2 rows and i want "margin-top:-50px" in the bottom row but distored for mobile and other view.. my code here;

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="myavatar col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
         <img src="1.png"  class="img-responsive">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-lg-4 br">a</div>
</div>
```

See the below given image

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is unclear, can you be more clear please?

Comment: Of course, I want to get up my red mark div.

Comment: but still applying `margin-top: -50px`? and where you that?

Comment: use like this   `$(".row").eq(1).css("margin-top","-50px");`

Comment: yes work this code. but distored on mobile view .  This image desktop = http://hizliresim.com/DJAEM6  and this image mobile view = http://hizliresim.com/81rkba

Comment: @OliviaOwen so the code should work only in desktop and not on mobile, right?

Comment: yes i will use your code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
if (!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  )) {
  $(".row").eq(1).css("margin-top", "-50px");
}
```

So what i am doing is I am checking whether the browser is mobile or not. And if it's not a mobile view, I am applying the css.

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: why use JS when media query can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question fully but try the following:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="myavatar col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <img src="1.png"  class="img-responsive">
   </div>
   <div  class="br col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   a
   </div>
 </div>
```

Do you want to show br in mobile view? or hide it?

Comment: i fixed here later. this my first row. i know here.